# Create script tags in Sendgrid Dynamic template

Tags: html, sendgrid, strapi, github-issues

What I need is I want to fetch an API using a button. I have created html template in sendgrid dynamic template from preview its working perfectly. But email the invisible.

After that I have removed button and check with anchor tag same issue not working.

[image: code sample]

email body its appearing but cannot click or do anything

[image: cannot click]

But in the html template all are working fine and APIs are fetching perfectly

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I regret to inform you that email clients block JavaScript from executing, so this cannot work.

You should make your unsubscribe button link to a page on your site in which your user can unsubscribe.

There are some circumstances in which you can run (sort of) JavaScript in some email clients. There is a framework called AMP4Email which allows you to use web components with extra behaviour within an email, you can read [an introduction to sending AMP emails here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-interactive-amp-email-twilio-sendgrid).